# How can I keep the network up when I close my laptop lid?

Tags: networking

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 on an asus laptop.
When I close the lid of the laptop, the laptop drops off my home network.

How can I keep its connection to network open?

Answer (score 5):

Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` with

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

and change/set

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Then apply this net setting with

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

I found this solution [here](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/).

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't happen under Ubuntu 18.04, as I'm typing to you with my laptop lid closed, using external keyboard, bluetooth mouse and monitor. Check your Settings->Power configuration. See my power saving screen shot.

[image]

You can alternatively turn off power saving for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth if they are giving you problems. I'm guessing your computer didn't enter suspense mode when you close your lid, if it is then check the automatic suspend settings.

Comment: If I toggle that setting then wifi just turns off, and remains off no matter whether the laptop is open or closed. That option completely disables wifi.

Comment: @bobdobbs turning off power saving for Wi-Fi and Bluetooth does not equal turning of Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. And if it still toggle off when you close the lid, you probably need to check if you BIOS is doing that for you. From there, make sure power saving is not turned on.